# FullCalendar PluginDef type in Angular 17

Tags: fullcalendar-6

Can anyone using FullCalender 6.1.11 in Angular 17, explain the CalendarOptions.plugins key.

All examples on the FC website show the plugins is an array with plugins, imported into the component as the following

```
import dayGridPlugin from '@fullcalendar/daygrid';
import interactionPlugin from '@fullcalendar/interaction';
```

and the option `plugins: [dayGridPlugin, interactionPlugin]`.

Version 6.1.11, this old notation doesn't work. From the code the plugins should be

```
interface PluginDef extends PluginHooks {
id: string;
name: string;
deps: PluginDef[];
```

}

In my component, I've entered:

```
plugins: [{id: '1', 'name':'DayGrid',deps: [dayGridPlugin]}]
```

I'm receiving an error on [dayGridPlugin],

Type 'PluginDef' is missing the following properties from type 'PluginDef': name, premiumReleaseDate, isLoadingFuncs, contextInit, and 9 more.ts(2740)

Can anyone from FullCalendar help me and others out on this issue?  Thanks.